# Has anyone obtained an invitation to SUN Cloud?

Tags: cloud-computing, sun

Does anyone here know how to get an early invitation to the Sun Cloud?

Comment: As ever in life, I'm sure it's not what you know, but who you know.

Answer (score 2):

From Sun's Cloud website:

Four Ways To Touch the Sun Cloud

Subscribe: Get on the list for the Early Access programs.

Share: Review and comment on developing cloud APIs.

Learn More: Get Sun's free guide to cloud computing architecture and infrastructure.

Join Us: Sun's partner initiative helps qualified companies with co-marketing and technology assistance.

Comment: Yes. Before I tried this forum I did all those steps.  I think Farseeker is right, you probably need to know someone ;).

Thanks